SSRS Report Server Data Source Hidden
How can be have the shared Data Source folder visible to all on Report Server 2014 which is hidden by particular user?

Thank You,
Dhara
I tried to check clicking Deatiled View on Report Server and also tried to create Data Source folder which gave me message that the Data Source is already exists.

It sounds like a permission issue

We have cross checked with existing users permission but still not visible. Is this due to a Permission issue? Could anyone confirm, please?

The Data Sources folder is hidden by default, you should be able to see if if you select "view / Show hidden items" from the web portal

I do not see View/Show Hidden items on the Report Server
